# Eloquent JS Asynchronous Programming example Promise.all

Tags: javascript

Not understanding this Promise example from Eloquent:

```
function availableNeighbors(nest) {
  let requests = nest.neighbors.map(neighbor => {
    return request(nest, neighbor, "ping")
      .then(() => true, () => false);
  });
  return Promise.all(requests).then(result => {
    return nest.neighbors.filter((_, i) => result[i]);
  });
}
```

Basically the scope of this function available neighbours it to tell whether the neighbour nests of nest are able to receive messages. Nest.neighbour is an array of all the neighbours of nest. Request function creates a promise. I get most of the code,basically it is mapping the array of nests to true for nests that receive messages, and false for the others.
The filter is supposed to remove all the nests that were rejected and hence have a value of false.

I cannot understand how this is happening though, how are the false nests removed?

Comment: `how are the false nests removed?` `return nest.neighbors.filter((_, i) => result[i]);`

Comment: Do you know what array.filter does?

Answer (score 0):

`result` is an array of the results of all the promises that were created by `map()`. The indexes of this array correspond to the indexes in the `nest.neighbors` array.

The filter callback function receives the values and indexes from the `nest.neighbors` array. It doesn't care about the values (the name `_` is a common convention to indicate an ignored parameter). All it cares about is the index -- it uses that to test the corresponding element of `result`. It returns that value, and if it's `true` then `filter()` will include that value in its result array.

Comment: Ok yes, that is a neat way of filtering would have never occurred to me thanks.